# Add column with different length as new column in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe I will call DF1:

[image]

I have the second dataframe, DF2 (with only 3 rows):

[image]

I want to create a new column in DF1 I will call total_population_by_year1 where:

total_population_by_year1 = (the content of DF2 if year DF1 == Year DF2)
In other words, the new column rows will be filled with the total population for each year.

What I have done so far:

```
df_tg = DF2.join(DF1[DF1.total_population_by_year == 
DF1.Year], ["Year", "Level_One_ICD", 
"total_patient_Level1_by_year"])
```

This returns an error.

Some ideas to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DF2 = DF2.toDF(['Year_2','total_population_by_year'])
DF1 = DF1.join(DF2, DF1.Year == DF2.Year_2).drop('Year_2')
```